# Creating Oracle TRIGGERS for shipment_status_af_update

Tags: oracle, triggers

I need to Create a trigger named 'shipment_status_af_update' that is triggered whenever the shipment_status table is updated.
This trigger will insert the name and action into the table 'status_log_history' after the updation of shipment_status details.
The action name in the affected log table status_log_history is 'After_Update_Shipment_Status'.

```
Hints:
Trigger name : shipment_status_af_update
Table name : status_log_history
Field names :name, action
Action  : 'After_Update_Shipment_Status'.
Hint: Add / after the end statement
```

My code is:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER shipment_status_af_update
AFTER UPDATE on shipment_status FOR EACH ROW declare
BEGIN

insert into status_log_history  (name,action) 
values(:new.name,'After_Update_Shipment_Status');

END;
/
```

Result:
Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

Comment: What does `show errors` tell you? Hard to advise you what to do without knowing what the actual error is...

Comment: No problem with DECLARE, @Suresh. Trigger compiles with, as well as without it.

Answer (score 0):

If both tables exist and contain names you used in trigger, code compiles:

```
SQL> create table shipment_status (name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> create table status_log_history(name varchar2(20), action varchar2(30));

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger shipment_status_af_update
  2    after update on shipment_status
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5  begin
  6    insert into status_log_history (name, action)
  7    values (:new.name, 'After_Update_Shipment_Status');
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```